# An ODE comparison problem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

Recently I met an ODE problem but after thinking for quite a while I still could not find an answer. Here is the question, which looks very simple:

---

Let $y=y(t)$ be a smooth function defined on $[0,\infty)$. If $y(t)$ satisfies the differential inequality
$$(ty')' \le \frac{4t}{(1+t^2)^2}(1-e^{2y})$$with the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$, then is it true that $y(t) \le 0$ for all $t \ge 0$?

---

The motivation is that if the above differential inequality becomes equality with same initial conditions, then $y(t) \equiv 0$. I strongly feel the answer is positive, but so far I don't know how to apply any comparison argument. Any ideas and comments will be fully appreciated.

---

Update: For the equality case, we can show $y(t) \equiv 0$ using the following argument:

Let $u(t)=\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+t^2}\right)$, then the equality case becomes 
$$(ty')'= te^{2u}(1-e^{2y})=-(tu')'-te^{2(u+y)}.$$ Let $w=u+y$, then $w$ solves the differential equation $(tw')'+te^{2w}=0$ with the initial condition $w'(0)=0$. Then $w$ must be of the form
$$w(t)=\ln\left(\frac{2c}{1+c^2t^2}\right)$$where $c$ is any positive constant. Hence $$y=w-u=\ln\left(\frac{c(1+t^2)}{1+c^2t^2}\right).$$Using the condition $y(0)=0$, we have $c=1$ and hence $y(t) \equiv 0$.

Comment: what about the equality case and doing a substitution y(t)=ln u(t)

Comment: @OOESCoupling, for the equality case, yes, one can find an explicit formula for the general solutions, but the inequality case becomes tricky. This substitution does not seem work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\vp}{\varepsilon}$
The conjecture is false. The previous answer, using numerics, was convincing enough for me, but perhaps not for others. So, here is a rigorous answer, based on the same general idea.

Let 
\begin{equation*}
 L(y)(t):=(ty'(t))'-\frac{4t}{(1+t^2)^2}(1-e^{2y(t)}). 
\end{equation*}
Then 
\begin{equation*}
 L(y_1)(t)=0
\end{equation*}
for real $t>0$, 
where 
\begin{equation*}
y_1(t):= \ln \frac{c_1^2 e^{c_1 c_2} t^{c_1-1}(t^2+1)}
{c_1^2 e^{2 c_1 c_2}+t^{2 c_1}} 
\end{equation*}
with $c_1\ge0$ and any real $c_2$. In what follows, set 
\begin{equation*}
 c_1:=\sqrt{197/199},\quad c_2:=1/192. 
\end{equation*}
Then 
\begin{equation*}
 y_1(3/10)\approx-0.000101955<0,\quad y_1'(3/10)\approx-0.0200123<0. 
\end{equation*}
Let now 
\begin{align*}
 c&:=-\frac{y_1'(3/10)^2}{4y_1(3/10)}\approx0.98203, \tag{1} \\ 
 \de&:=\frac{2y_1(3/10)}{y_1'(3/10)}\approx0.0101893, \tag{2} \\ 
 \vp&:=3/10-\de\approx0.289811, \tag{3}
\end{align*}
so that 
\begin{equation*}
 c\de^2=-y_1(3/10),\quad 2c\de=-y_1'(3/10). \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
Letting now 
\begin{equation*}
 y_2(t):=-c(t-\vp)^2, \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
we see that 
\begin{equation*}
 y_2(\vp)=y_2'(\vp)=0,\quad y_2(3/10)=y_1(3/10),\quad y_2'(3/10)=y_1'(3/10), \tag{6}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
 L(y_2)(t)=c(3/5-2 \de-4 t)+
 4 t \,\frac{e^{-2 c (\de+t-3/10)^2}-1}{(t^2+1)^2}
 <c(3/5-2 \de-4 t)<c(3/5-4 \vp)<-0.544<0 \tag{7}
\end{equation*}
for $t\ge\vp$. 
Letting finally 
\begin{equation*}
 Y:=y_1\,1_{[3/10,\infty)}+y_2\,1_{[\vp,3/10)},
\end{equation*}
we see that 
\begin{equation*}
 L(Y)\le0
\end{equation*}
on $[0,\infty)$. However, 
\begin{equation*}
 Y(6)=y_1(6)\approx0.00360808>0. 
\end{equation*}

---

The function $Y$ is the solution $y$ to the problem 
$$L(y)=h$$ 
on $(0,\infty)$ with the initial conditions $y(0+)=y'(0+)=0$, where $h:=L(Y)\le0$ and $Y''$ is understood as the right (or left) derivative of $Y'$. Also, $Y=0$ on $(0,\vp]$ and $Y(6)>0.003>0$.

Let now $\psi$ be a function in $C^\infty((0,\infty))$ such that $\psi=0$ on $(0,\vp/2]$ and $\psi\le0$ on $(0,\infty)$. Let then $Z$ be the solution $z$ to the problem $$L(z)=\psi$$ 
on $(0,\infty)$ with the initial conditions $z(0+)=z'(0+)=0$ (so that $z(\vp/2)=z'(\vp/2)=0$). Choose now $\psi$ to be so close to $h$ in $L^1((0,\infty))$ that $|Z(6)-Y(6)|<0.001$. Then $Z(6)>0.002>0$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and contribution. This is really inspriational and deserves upvote. I observed that the $Y$ constructed above are two functions glued together, which is $C^2$ but not $C^{\infty}$. I'm curious that does the conjecture hold true for any $C^{\infty}$ functions $y$ satisfying the inequality $L(y)\le 0$?

Comment: Just realized that the function $Y$ constructed above is $C^1$, not $C^2$, so the second derivative cannot be defined at the point $x=3/10$.

Comment: @student : I have added details concerning a $C^\infty$ version.

Comment: I still have two questions: First, why the $L^1$ approximation of $L$ lead to $L^{\infty}$ approximation of solutions. Second, is it possible to give a concrete function $y(t)$ such that the $y(t)$ satisfies the differential inequality while positive somewhere?

Comment: (i) If you go over a standard proof of the continuous dependence of the solution to an ODE $y'=f(t,y,\theta)$ on a parameter -- see e.g. https://users.math.msu.edu/users/hhu/848/lec_5.pdf, Theorem 5.2 -- you will see that the condition of the $L^\infty$-boundedness of $f$ can be replaced by the $L^1$-boundedness. Here you'll need to use the absolute continuity of the integral: if $\int|g|\,d\mu<\infty$ then $\int_A|g|\,d\mu\to0$ whenever $\mu(A)\to0$. (This easily follows by dominated convergence.) In your case, $A$ will be the short intervals of a partition of the interval $[0,6]$, say.

Comment: (ii) If you want an explicit $C^\infty$ counterexample to your conjecture, just follow all the many steps of the procedure I have described, doing explicit estimates at each step. The result will be an explicit function, though with a huge and cumbersome description. If you want something better than that, you may want to ask this additional question in a separate post.

Comment: I still could not see the continuous dependence of the solution from the theorem, because here $L$ involves second order derivatives.

Comment: @student : It a standard trick to rewrite higher-order ODEs as first-order vector ODEs, that is, first-order systems of scalar ODEs. E.g., rewrite $y''=f(t,y,y')$ as a system of two first-order ODEs: $y'=z$ and $z'=f(t,y,z)$ -- or, in the vector form, $X'=F(t,X)$, where $X:=(y,z)$ and $F(t,X):=(z,f(t,y,z))$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I have one last quesion, which is my main doubt on this solution. The function $Y$ constructed is not $C^2$ since its second derivative has a jump at $x=10/3$ as seen in the construction, then $Y$ is not a classical solution to the ODE. I checked the proof in the notes you posted, but I think that proof does require the solution is a classical one.

Comment: @student : When you rewrite the (vector) ODE in the (more general) integral form (as is of course done in the proof at the link I provided), then you'll see that it is enough for the vector solution to the vector ODE to be just continuous -- which corresponds to the solution of the original scalar second-order ODE being in $C^1$, which is exactly what we have.

Comment: I do very appreicate your time, but I'm still very confused... That theorem says the solutions depend continuously on the parameters $(t, x, \lambda)$, but in your context, you use a function $\psi$ to $L^1$ approximate $h$. How can the solution continuously depend on the $L^1$ continuity of functions? Could you possibly elaborate this step in the answer? I would be really appreciated.

Comment: @student : Just use the linear (say) interpolation $(1-\theta)h+\theta h_\infty$ between the discontinuous right-hand side $h$ and its $C^\infty$ approximation $h_\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture is very likely false. Indeed, let $Y$ be the solution of the ODE
$$(ty'(t))'=\frac{4t}{(1+t^2)^2}(1-e^{2y(t)})-1_{[0.3,0.31]}(t)$$ 
with the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$.

Then $Y=0$ on $[0,0.3]$, and the shown below numerical solution of the above ODE strongly suggests that $Y(6)>0$. We solve this ODE (numerically) first on the interval $[0.3,0.31]$ and then on the interval $[0.31,8]$.

A rigorous but tedious proof of the claim that $Y(6)>0$ could be obtained by estimating well enough each of the steps of the procedure for the numerical solution of this ODE.

[image]